# Should you backup registers before calling a C Standrd Library function?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, standard-library

- In assembly, should you backup registers before calling a C Standard Library function?
- Does the Standard Library guarantee that all of its functions backup the caller's registers and recover them in the end?
- Where can I find official information about this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is platform specific, usually you don't need to specifically save and restore registers at the call site, the callee usually does it. You just need to follow the linkage convention for your particular platform. The C-library is not state-less, it is generally not a good idea to just call some functions without initializing the library as it is done in a typical c program object which contains main().

Answer (score 3):

I think just calling conventions apply here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

The C standard library does not guarantee that it's functions backup registers for the caller. It depends on the calling conventions and how it's handled by a complier.

Assume that a C function knows nothing about registers.

You'll find which calling convention a function is using, form the function's declaration/signature. Default should be cdecl.

Answer (score 2):

This is a platform-specific question, not just a hardware-specific question. The C standard library is designed to be called from a C program, where calling conventions are (generally) handled at compile-time and the appropriate register and stack manipulations are done for you.

Consult the platform-specific ABI guide for your platform to determine how to call an externally linked function.

Comment: How do I find the ABI guide for my platform? (pardon the ignorance).

Comment: That depends--what platform are you using? Windows 32-bit? 64-bit? Mac OS X 32-bit? 64-bit? A particular flavour of Linux? MS-DOS?

Comment: @LeifEricson What H2CO3 is telling you to do is to look it up for yourself, since we are not your research assistants.